# Making a textfile into a dictionary PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert this textfile into a dictionary, but it does not seem to work.

```
eggs 5
spam 3
cool 2
yolk 3
milk 5
```

```
def openspam():
     badwordsfile = open("FulaOrd0.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
     for words in badwordsfile:
          d = {}
          word, value = words.rstrip().split(None, 1)
          d[word] = value
     return d

d = openspam()
```

When I check what "d", is in the shell. I get "{"milk": 5}. I want to get {"eggs": 5, "spam": 3, "cool": 2, "yolk": 3, "milk": 5}

does anyone see what I have done wrong?

Comment: look at where you initialize `d`

Comment: just a small criticism: you should consider using `with` instead of the naked `open()`. This is exactly what [context managers](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) were created for.

Answer (score 5):

Move `d = {}` outside the loop. Otherwise, you're erasing its contents during each iteration.

```
def openspam():
     badwordsfile = open("FulaOrd0.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
     d = {}
     for words in badwordsfile:
          word, value = words.rstrip().split(None, 1)
          d[word] = value
     return d

d = openspam()
```

Comment: @EdwardSikorski you should accept Kevin's answer if it worked for you